# Background Job Killed After 2-3 hours without any error on logs

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, parquet

I am running a machine learning job. The Job produces parquet files. Each file size is 30-40MB. Total size of the these files is 11-12 GB.

Below piece of code I am having to create panda data frame and this never get executed and Job getting killed.

```
dataset = pq.ParquetDataset('out/{}/sales/'.format(self.cfg.banner_name), metadata_nthreads=mp.cpu_count())
        df = dataset.read().to_pandas()
```

Please suggest the reason of job is getting killed.